# Slate Functions Editor - 1 Table with 2 columns - Sort ASC

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I has a table with 2 columns: id_pk and str_name_last_first
How can I sort this table by name? if i use lower one.. the id-pk does not fit anymore to name.

```
var data = {{q_data}}
// data.str_name_last_first.sort();

return data
```

this example does not works:

```
employees.sort(function(a, b){
    var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase()
    if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
        return -1 
    if (nameA > nameB)
        return 1
    return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy if you have the result :-)

```
var data = {{f_data}}
var data_rows = transformColumnSchemaToRowSchema(data);

data_rows.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.str_team_name - b.str_team_name;
});

data_rows.sort((a, b) => {
    let fa = a.str_name.toLowerCase(),
        fb = b.str_name.toLowerCase();

    if (fa < fb) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (fa > fb) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});

return transformRowSchemaToColumnSchema(data_rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

if the `{{q_data}}` is a Postgres SQL I recommend adding an ORDER BY in the query

```
SELECT * from table ORDER BY str_name_last_first ASC
```

if the `{{q_data}}` is a phonograph query using the search service then add this to your search request json

```
 "sort": {
   "str_name_last_first": {
   "order": "asc"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Something to add: As far as my test went, this sort function does not work for string columns. Probably with numeric columns. I could not tell for sure because I unfortunately don't have numeric column to do a test. hth

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `q_data` is a standard postgres query, in which the results of your query look like this (you can see this in Slate if you click the `</>` button in the Query results preview panel):

```
{
  id_pk: ["a", "c", "b"],
  str_name_last_first: ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
}
```

You almost certainly want to implement sorting as part of the query rather than sorting with a Slate javascript function, which does the "work" of sorting in browser memory. In that case, you simply add an `ORDER BY` statement to your SQL query.

If, for some reason, you really do need to do some sorting in a Slate javascript function, then with this data structure the easiest approach is to:

1. Covert the single object with parallel lists of values (column structure) to a single *list* with key/value pairs for each column (row structure).
2. Sort the list of objects
3. Convert the list of objects back to a parallel columns data structure.

The Slate documentation has some example implementation of the conversion between these two commonly used formats for representing tabular data: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/references-convert-rows-columns/